# how to write a script that only acts on new log entries

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, bash, logging, scripting

I feel like this should be a simple thing but I am having a hard time figuring it out.

I am trying to write a script that will monitor one of the apache log files and take some specific action.  But how should I go about monitoring the log file?

Everytime a new line is written to log, I want that entry to be checked to see if it matches what I am looking for and if so x happens. When I am doing this manually I used cat or tail -f.  I dont want to run the script every 30 seconds via cron and go through the whole log (or even the last 5 lines), figure out which of those lines are new since the last time the script ran and then so some things.

Is there a way only check the single new entry in the log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running your script via cron but using `logtail` or [`logtail2`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logtail2) to read the file will avoid reading the whole file every minute.  Logtail keeps track of where it last read to and jumps to that point the next time you use it.

If you want to act on new log lines immediately rather than waiting up to 59 seconds between cron invocations, you will have to use `tail -f` or some equivalent.

Janne's and Khaled's answers both look to solve this problem well.

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of the already available Linux tools like `tail`, `grep`, and `named pipes`. First, create a named pipe (fifo) using:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/myfifo
```

Second, create a simple script that will read from this fifo file. Here is a simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash
pipe=/tmp/myfifo

while true
do
    if read line <$pipe; then
        if [[ "$line" == 'quit' ]]; then
            break
        fi
        echo $line
    fi
done
echo "Reader exiting"
```

This script reads from the named pipe and prints the line to stdout until it gets the "quit" word. This is just an example that can be customized.

Third, use `tail` to read new lines that are appended to apache log file and redirect the output to the named pipe.

```
$ tail -n0 -F /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep some_text > /tmp/myfifo
```

The `-F` option means to follow the file by name which should make it immune to logrotate. So, it will follow always the same file name. The `-n0` means to not get any old line. The `grep` is useful to direct only the relevant lines.

Using this solution, you don't need any cron job. Just run the script and the tail command shown above.

Comment: What's the reasoning of using a named pipe here instead of just piping the output of grep into your script?

Comment: Named pipes are just like unnamed ones created using `|`, but it may be easier and clearer to use named pipes in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `syslog-ng` (probably `rsyslogd` will do too) as syslog-daemon, you can use that.

Just configure it to keep an eye on Apache log file, or alternatively configure Apache to send logs to syslog facility with `CustomLog` directive and `logger`.

Syslog-daemon will then use pattern matching and perform $foo if some match is found. For example, in syslog-ng you can set up a log file hook and filter it like this:

```
source apache_log { file("/var/log/apache2/access.log"); };
filter apache_match { match("GET /evilscript.php"); };
```

And then syslog-ng call external script

```
destination apache_logmatch_script { program("/usr/local/bin/apachematch.pl"); };
```

Finally put all of those together:

```
log { source(apache_log); filter(apache_match); destination apache_logmatch_script); };
```

If using this technique, syslog-ng will spawn your script background waiting for new stuff to appear. Because of this you need to modify your scripts to wait for input from STDIN; here's a short Perl example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$|=1;
while (<>) {
     printf "Stuff happened, I got this entry: %s!\n", $_;
}
```

I'm not going deeper with my reply until I know you want to try this technique.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a record of the last line you read. On each new run read from the last+1 line to the end of file and update record.

But keep in mind the logfile might get rotated. So you should keep a record of the inode number for example.

[fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) does implement logfile monitoring the way you seem to want it. Maybe take a look at it? Either you could borrow some ideas or actually use it.

Comment: +1 for fail2ban. The first thing I thought when reading the question

Comment: thanks.  fail2ban looks good and while I'm not trying to ban anyone, the general premise is the same. But... its in python, which I've never used before and everything else on our systems are bash or perl.

Answer (score 0):

You could use diff.  Copy the log file to a temp file.

Take a diff of the live log file and the temp file.

Run the pattern matching on the resultant diff.

Idea taken from the nagios check_log plugin.  See http://www.kilala.nl/Sysadmin/index.php?id=715 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If fail2ban is not suited to your needs, you can try and modify [flog.c](http://pastebin.com/8hxSmTCE) which was written by Markus J. Ranum:

*"This little utility does the equivalent of "tail -f" but is smart
enough to handle changing files if a log rotater moves the file out
from under the user while we're running. Also, unlike "tail -f" this
program is smart enough to exit when the user logs out(!) and will
not spew logs to the pty forever. No effort is made at elegance or
performance."*

You can modify to check whether any new line matches your desired pattern and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a python solution, check out Pygtail: https://github.com/bgreenlee/pygtail

It's based on `logcheck`'s `logtail2` tool

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line;
do
      echo $line > /tmp/output.log
      mail -s 'Event Msg.' 'email@gmail.com' < /tmp/output.log
done < <(tail -n0 -F /var/adm/messages)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included an explanation with your code.